# resize InfoWidow height according to content thus removing the scroll bar

Tags: css, jsp, google-maps-api-3

What i am looking for is a way to resize the height of the infowindow so that all the data in my  appears in the infowindow.

[image]

As is visible from the screenshot. the data in different infowindows is basically a table with 2 columns and variable number of rows.

from the screenshot-
The "Baba Haridas Nagar" infowindow is perfect.
however if the row size increase a scroll bar pops up which hides the second column.
I want all of the rows to be displayed without the scroll bar(increase the height of the infowindow appropriately show that it dissappears :P)

Setting the div max height in the content itself works, but only upto a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to set a specific height for multiple reasons. A quick and easy fix to this issue would be to add a container to your infoWindow (say a DIV), give your container a 10 or 20px right margin or padding, then add your content into the container. This way, you can ensure the scroll bar will not be over your content.

```
var contentString = '<div id="content" style="margin-right:20px;">'+
'Your content here'+
'</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/VFyYb/

Edit:

As per Google documentation: If you wish to explicitly size the content, you can put it in a DIV element and style the DIV with CSS. You can use CSS to enable scrolling too. Note that if you do not enable scrolling and the content exceeds the space available in the info window, the content may spill out of the info window. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Comment: This could be part of an intermediate solution.
however I wish to display all the data in the infowindow. The user should not need to scroll down, rather the infowindo height should be dynamically increased to fit "ALL" of the data

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but as I said, I would not do it this way. Unless it is a very private project, you have to think about people with smaller screens. What will happen if the InfoWindow content is bigger than the map itself? Please see my updated answer.